Matching number of a graph is equal to the independence number of its line graph.
Let $\alpha'(G)$ the matching number of a graph $G$, $L(G)$ its line graph and $\alpha(L(G))$ the stability number of its line graph. I need to prove that $\alpha'(G)=\alpha(L(G))$. Let $M$ be a maximum matching for the graph $G$, i.e. $|M|=\alpha'(G)$.
Vertices of $L(G)$ are the edges of $G$ such that two vertices are connected if and only if they have the an endpoint in common.
If an edge $e$ belongs to $M$, then its adjacent edges don't belong to the matching by definition. In $L(G)$, $e$ is connected to these adjacent edges.
If now we consider $e'\in M$ such that $e\neq e'$, $e'\not\in N_{L(G)}(e)$ (neighborhood of $e$ in $L(G)$), because if $e'\in N_{L(G)}(e)$, then we would have adjacent edges of $M$ in $G$, which is not possible.
Then, with the edges of $M$ we found an stable set in $L(G)$.
Therefore, $$\alpha(L(G))\leq|M|=\alpha'(G)\implies \alpha(L(G))\leq\alpha'(G).$$
To prove the other inequality in order to obtain the equality, I tried assuming the $\alpha(L(G))>\alpha'(G)$ but I'm stuck. Maybe doing a similar reasoning for this converse?

You've shown that every matching in $G$ gives an independent set in $L(G)$; now prove that every independent set in $L(G)$ gives a matching in $G$. This should be enough.
